# Apache Beam reads data from 2 input sources and unable to join data correctly in some cases

Tags: java, apache-beam

I want to be able to read messages from 2 PubSub topics and associate the second message to the first message.
For example say we read user scores from a pubsub topic "scores" and who is the winner from another pub sub topic "results". Note that I use .withTimestampAttribute("timestamp") when I read from pubsub so it can use event time for processing and also if the scores message is associated with the results message then the event time for both messages will be set same when published to pubsub. The streaming pipeline should be able to output a result as to who won and who lost among the users.
This will write output every minute to Google Cloud Storage.

Below is my code snippet that tries to do that, but the issue is while trying to associate these 2 messages, few edge cases do not work. Say for instance, I know for a fact that the results as to who the winner is, will be available only after the scores for that event occurs. Hence I want to allow extra 5 minutes for it to arrive.
But when I try to CoGroupByKey these 2 messages one doesn't wait for the other.

```
//Read from PubSub
PCollection<String> scoresInput = pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().withTimestampAttribute("timestamp")
.fromTopic("projects/test/topics/scores"));
PCollection<String> winInput = pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().withTimestampAttribute("timestamp")
.fromTopic("projects/test/topics/results"));

//Apply some transformation on the scores message
PCollection<KV<String, User>> scoreToTrx = scoresInput.apply(Window.<String> 
into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()))
            .discardingFiredPanes()
            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractScoresToTransactionIdFn()));

//group by all common trx
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<User>>> scoresToTrxGrouped =  
scoreToTrx.apply(GroupByKey.<String, User>create());

//Create one object with array of users for transaction. Users(transactionid, 
//array of all user names, array of all scores, array of win info(defaulted to 
//false))
PCollection<KV<String, Users>> users = scoresToTrxGrouped.apply(ParDo.of(new 
ProcessAllUsersAndScoresToTransactionIdFn()));

//Apply some transformation on the results message
PCollection<KV<String, Winner>> winToTrx = winInput.apply(Window.<String> 
into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()))
            .discardingFiredPanes()
            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(5)))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractWinToTransactionIdFn()));

//Now associate the user score to winner.
final TupleTag<Users> scoreTag = new TupleTag<Users>();
final TupleTag<Winner> winTag = new TupleTag<Winner>();

PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> trxIdToUserAndWinnerCoGbkResult = 
KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(scoreTag, users)
            .and(winTag, winToTrx).apply(CoGroupByKey.<String> create());

//The dofn here will check if the winner is present in the users list and then 
//update the wininfo of that user to 
//winner.       
PCollection<String> joinUserToWinner = trxIdToUserAndWinnerCoGbkResult
            .apply(ParDo.of(new MapWinnerToUserForTransactionFn(scoreTag, 
winTag)));
```

Say for example I posted the below score message at event time Oct 12, 2017 at 4.12.04 pm

{
"transactionId": "1234",
"userName": "Amy",
"score": "10"
}

Then another one at Oct 12, 2017 at 4.12.20 pm

{
   "transactionId": "1234",
   "userName": "Becca",
   "score": "7"
}

Finally the winner is posted at Oct 12, 2017 at 4.15.20 pm

{
   "transactionId": "1234",
   "winner": "Amy"
}

Since it is a Fixed Window of 1 minute, So the window for this case will be [4.12.00,4.13.00) but since the winner falls outside of this window it will not be considered and it outputs as no winner.

{
    "transactionId": "1234",
    "users": ["Amy","Becca"],
    "scores": ["10","7"],
    "winInfo": ["loser","loser"]
}

Another case that can happen is when results message reach the pipeline before the scores because the score messages are may be waiting to be triggered after groupby, In that case the results message is getting discarded cause it is not able to associate with any scores and the output is same again with no winner even though there was a winner.

Note it is ok in some cases where data is too late I don't want to wait for them. 
But simple cases of 1:1 association say there is only 1 user score and 1 winner is not honored.

If I am reading from one input source I understand i can tweak my triggers to achieve what I want, but in my case the data is from 2 different sources and is dependent on each other to produce correct results.

My question is how can we honor cases like these where triggering of one is dependent on another input data.